# How to display the graphical decision tree for this scikit-learn decision tree script?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have this simple python scikit-learn script to demonstrate gender classification using decision tree algo.

https://github.com/Sarbjyotsingh/Gender-Classification-with-Python

```
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# [height, weight, shoe_size]
X = [[181, 80, 44], [177, 70, 43], [160, 60, 38], [154, 54, 37], [166, 65, 40],
     [190, 90, 47], [175, 64, 39],
     [177, 70, 40], [159, 55, 37], [171, 75, 42], [181, 85, 43]]

Y = ['male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female',
     'female', 'male', 'male']

clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
prediction = clf.predict([[160, 60, 22]])
print(prediction)
```

The script works fine. How can I modify it to display the graphical tree that shows how the decision tree interprets the input data to predict the output?

I am using python 3.7, scikit-learn 0.21.3

Comment: You might want to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718309/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-order-of-nodes-categorizing-data-in-decision-trees-whe/57737259#57737259

Comment: Why the 2 negative votes? Can those who downvote care to explain so that I know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# [height, weight, shoe_size]
X = [[181, 80, 44], [177, 70, 43], [160, 60, 38], [154, 54, 37], [166, 65, 40],
     [190, 90, 47], [175, 64, 39],
     [177, 70, 40], [159, 55, 37], [171, 75, 42], [181, 85, 43]]

Y = ['male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female',
     'female', 'male', 'male']

clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
prediction = clf.predict([[160, 60, 22]])
print(prediction)

import graphviz
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph.render("gender")
```

The last line will generate a pdf `gender.pdf` which displays the decision tree.